# dos2unix cannot follow symlink if link targets file on another partition

Tags: linux, symlink

I have a text file `a.txt` with CRLF endings which is the target of a symbolic link `link.txt`.
By default, `dos2unix` does not follow symbolic links. I have to add `--follow-symlink` for that.

It works if `a.txt` and `link.txt` are on the same partition. Otherwise, it fails.

Example :

```
pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ file a.txt
a.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ ln -s a.txt link.txt

pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ dos2unix link.txt
dos2unix: Skipping symbolic link link.txt.

pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ dos2unix --follow-symlink link.txt
dos2unix: converting file link.txt to Unix format...

pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ file a.txt
a.txt: ASCII text

pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ ln -s /home/pi/a.txt /mnt/mountpoint/link.txt

# Revert a.txt to CRLF endings
pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ unix2dos a.txt
unix2dos: converting file a.txt to DOS format...

pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ file a.txt
a.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

pi@raspberrypi(rw):~$ dos2unix --follow-symlink /mnt/mountpoint/link.txt
dos2unix: problems renaming '/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpS6Oz6x' to '/home/pi/a.txt': Invalid cross-device link
          which is the target of symbolic link '/mnt/mountpoint/link.txt'
          output file remains in '/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpS6Oz6x'
dos2unix: problems converting file /mnt/mountpoint/link.txt
```

How can I solve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dos2unix` first makes a change to a temporary file, and then uses the `rename(2)` system call to move it back to the destination.

```
$ strace -e trace=rename dos2unix --follow-symlink /mnt/mountpoint/link.txt
rename("/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpt4sobL", "/home/pi/a.txt") = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
dos2unix: problems renaming '/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpt4sobL' to '/home/pi/a.txt': Invalid cross-device link
          which is the target of symbolic link '/mnt/mountpoint/link.txt'
          output file remains in '/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpt4sobL'
dos2unix: converting file /mnt/mountpoint/link.txt to Unix format ...
dos2unix: problems converting file /mnt/mountpoint/link.txt
+++ exited with 18 +++
```

You see it made the change to a temporary file called `/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpt4sobL`:

```
$ file /mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpt4sobL
/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpt4sobL: ASCII text
```

But then it couldn't rename it back to the target because they are or different filesystems, as you can see in the output of `strace`:

```
rename("/mnt/mountpoint/d2utmpt4sobL", "/home/pi/a.txt") = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
```

In the man pages of `rename(2)` you'll see:

```
       EXDEV  oldpath  and  newpath  are  not  on the same mounted filesystem.
              (Linux permits a filesystem to be mounted  at  multiple  points,
              but  rename()  does not work across different mount points, even
              if the same filesystem is mounted on both.)
```

The only solution would be to change target itself, and not the link. You can find the target of the link by using the `readlink -f` / `readlink --canonicalize` command

```
$ file /home/pi/a.txt
/home/pi/a.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

$ dos2unix $(readlink -f /mnt/mountpoint/link.txt)
dos2unix: converting file /home/pi/a.txt to Unix format ...

$ file /home/pi/a.txt
/home/pi/a.txt: ASCII text
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is there a similiar way to make this thing work either if link.txt is a link or a regular file ?

Comment: @fdamien12 not unless you fix the source code of `dos2unix`. Or you can create a wrapper script or an alias. BTW, my solution would work even if link.txt is a regular file.

Comment: OK, indeed your solution works even on a regular file. I made a mistake when testing the behaviour of readlink on a regular file and I thought it would work only on links.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I will address this issue in the next dos2unix version. You can file problems at https://sourceforge.net/p/dos2unix/bugs/ or email me directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved in dos2unix 7.5.1.

The temporary file is created on the target file system. There is no moving across file systems any more.